# d3 - how to add color to path object

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors, path, line

I'm working on a project where I want a specific section of a line graph to be colored differently based on its value.  I am POSITIVE the color function works because I can change the text color of the tooltip to match what I want.  However, I cannot get the line itself to change color.  I'm pretty sure that I'm missing some insight on the different between d and data...

Here's the relevant code:

```js
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.avgs); });

d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/emcmahon013/850af022a2d9adc4b82a/raw/f2b553737d3772a206dd3b280366c61d301a141c/temp.csv", function(error, data) {               
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.phase= color(d.phase);
        d.avgs = +d.avgs;

    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([40, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.sensor; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    lineSvg.append("path")                                 // **********
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data))
        .attr("stroke",function(data){return d.phase;}) //THIS IS THE PROBLEM!
        .attr("stroke-width",2);
```

In addition, the following code does not work:

```js
.attr("stroke",function(data){return data.phase;})
```

I can place a colorblock function that will work.  If the d[i] value (where i= my index) corresponds to red, it will paint red, and if it corresponds to blue will paint blue.  I just can't figure out how to get the i values and make this dynamic.  Please help!

```js
    .attr("stroke",function(data) {return colorblock();}


function colorblock() {
    d=data[0];            //will return red line
    return d.phase;
}

       
function colorblock() {
    d=data[310];            //will return blue line
    return d.phase;
}
```

Comment: The SVG `path` element has only one color. So you can’t apply multiple colors to the one `path`.

Answer (score 0):

You've identified the line with the problem correctly.  You're using an undefined variable.

Original:

```
.attr("stroke",function(data){return d.phase;}) //THIS IS THE PROBLEM!
```

What you probably wanted:

```
.attr("stroke",function(data){return data.phase;}) //THIS IS THE SOLUTION!
```

Comment: It looks like the line above also has an error: `.attr("d", valueline(data))` should probably have a function closure: `.attr("d", function(data) { return valueline(data); })`.